# ERD Mapping - Relational Database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, mapping, erd

With in my ERD I have a disjoint mandatory relationship. See the following example.

[image]

** Assume "Teen" and "Adult" entities have their own unique attributes.

How to map this kind of a relation ship. And how to implement this with in tables.

[As I know you have to create two tables  called "Teen" and "Adult". Both have the same primary key "st_id". But the problem is, in both tables the "st_id" has to be unique since the relationship is mandatory. How to implement that?]

Example:

```
**Teen**                               
st_id | name
001     AA
002     BB

**Adult**
st_id | name
(as the st_id you can't have the value 001 again since it is already in the Teen table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is stopping you from having three tables:

```
STUDENT [PK: st_id] (optionally also an attribute of type BOOLEAN or similar, "is_teen" or "is_adult")
TEEN    [PK: st_id]
ADULT   [PK: st_id]
```

We will add one row into STUDENT for every new student; each time you add a student, then create a TEEN row if the new student is a teen, otherwise create a new ADULT row.
In either case, the st_id to use will be that of the new student.  The st_ids in TEEN and STUDENT will be mutually exclusive, but all st_ids will point back to the appropriate STUDENT row.

Your ERD snippet appears to be for a Logical Data Model; I have copied that into the physical implementation directly.  In the real world, often we would "roll up" (denormalize) the TEEN and ADULT attributes into the STUDENT entity to limit the amount of joining needed to get to all the info. available for a given student.

Optionally, you may choose to define a pair of foreign key relationships between STUDENT and TEEN and between STUDENT and ADULT.

Comment: But in mapping rules, when there is a mandatory disjoint you only map and create tables for the sub types right (Here for "Teen" and "Adult"). You don't map or implement the super type (Student). Above shown is only an example. In my real scenario I have 7 sub types with their unique attributes. So as you said putting all the sub types into a singles will create a huge table, which I don't think very useful. What is your opinion on that? Addition to that wont it is against the mapping rules?

Comment: If you choose not to map the STUDENT entity, you cannot express the "Mandatory" nature of the Mandatory, Disjoint relationship.  Depends on your needs, but in Logical Modelling, super and subtypes are almost always specified, otherwise the model makes little sense.  In physical implementation terms, without instantiating the supertype, you will need to carry all the common STUDENT attribs. in each subtype entity.

Comment: First thank you for the reply friend. Could you explain about this statement a little more. 

"In physical implementation terms, without instantiating the supertype, you will need to carry all the common STUDENT attribs. in each subtype entity"

Comment: And finally as you said it is ok to denormalize and create a table for the supertype in a mandatory disjoint, to maintain the mandatory nature. As an example for the above shown ERD, i have to add addition two fields type of boolean "isTeen" and "isAdult". for and example if "isTeen" is true i have to programmatically insert the additional attributes into the Teen table also by inserting the same PK in Student table as the PK of Teen table. Is that correct?

Comment: On your second point, you will need to add a TEEN or ADULT row manually, as required, and set that row's PK to be the same value as the STUDENT row's PK.
There are other ways of achieving the same 'linking' between STUDENT and ADULT/TEEN that offer greater flexibility, but this appears sufficient for this exercise. I hope this helps :)

Comment: And on this:

"In physical implementation terms, without instantiating the supertype, you will need to carry all the common STUDENT attribs. in each subtype entity"

I suggest that STUDENTs have attributes; if you don't create a STUDENT table then the attributes of STUDENT will need to be retained in each TEEN or ADULT table, as appropriate (unless you do not care about the STUDENT attributes in your example, in which case they can be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use 1 table for teen and adult like this

```
person
------
id         int
name       varchar
is_adult   bit

study
-------
id         int
person_id  int
...
```

Comment: I want to know how implement a disjoint mandatory in tables. Please if you can explain using the above shown ERD. I think the answer you given not contains ant disjoint scenario.

Comment: "Why not use 1 table for teen and adult like this"

Because each teen and adult have their own unique attributes. So you can't put all the attributes in a single "person" table.